# The content property isn't displayed in FireFox

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to display my CSS content in FireFox. It doesn't seem to be displaying correctly. Here is the code:

```
div.images:hover {
   content:url(http://domain.com/images.png);
}
```

Why does the content hover not display right on modzilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property is meant for the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore)/[`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) [**pseudo elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). Therefore it isn't suppose to work on something like `div.images:hover`.

Instead, use the `background` property to add the styling:

```
div.images:hover {
   background-image: url(http://domain.com/images.png);
}
```

Comment: No that still does not display

Comment: @AnaesArias Because you need to set a `width`/`height` on it.. http://jsfiddle.net/WXU4m/